# Delete multiple tables even without relationship

Tags: php, mysql

Deleting multiple table is possible if the rest of tables are related to the reference table.

```
TABLE1              |   TABLE2              |   TABLE3
id      username    |   id      username    |   id      username
1       userA       |   1       userA       |   1       userA
2       userB       |   2       userB       |   2       userB
```

-

```
DELETE T1, T2, T3 FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.username='$user'
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T3.username='$user'
WHERE T1.username='$user'
```

And now I don't know how to handle a situation where the reference table (at the code above T1 is the reference) is not related to the other.

```
TABLE1              |   TABLE2              |   TABLE3
id      username    |   id      username    |   id      username
1       userC       |   1       userA       |   1       userA
2       userD       |   2       userB       |   2       userB
```

EXAMPLE:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3 WHERE username='userA'
```

Do I have to delete them one by one or is there an existing MYSQL query for this?

Comment: Do a SELECT with the same condition and see what would get deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example basically produces Cartesian product. Deleting from multiple table in single query relates to tables having relation. As you do not have relationship between tables, you will have to delete them one by one.

Also your example statement have to qualify the column name with the table name.

> DELETE FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3 WHERE username='userA'

But we do not know which table has the value. Putting where clause with **AND** condition will not delete record from any table if any of the table do not meet the condition

```
(TABLE1.username='userA' AND TABLE2.username='userA' AND TABLE3.username='userA')
```

Similarly **OR** condition will delete data from all the tables if any one of them has a record matching the condition.

Comment: "DELETE FROM t1, t2, t3 WHERE t1.username='userB' OR t2.username='userB' OR t2.username='userB'" is not a valid sql syntax